# Force chrome tabs to crash

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension that crashes all tabs in chrome window so that they don't load on opening chrome (when having too many tabs).

But when I try to use

> chrome.tabs.update(null, {url:"chrome://crash"})

or

> chrome.tabs.update(null, {url:"about:crash"})

they don't work, although using

> chrome.tabs.update(null, {url:"chrome://tasks"})

works well

Is there any workaround to do that?

when this works too I'd like to loop on all the open tabs to do the same thing and I don't know how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you force Chrome pages/tabs to crash using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965987/how-do-you-force-chrome-pages-tabs-to-crash-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply getAll active windows and loop through its tabs then change its url to data:text/html

```
chrome.windows.getAll({populate : true}, function (window_list) {
    var list = [];
    for(var i=0;i<window_list.length;i++) {
        list = list.concat(window_list[i].tabs);
    }
    for(var y=0;y<list.length;y++) {
         var jsRunner = {'code': 'window.stop()'};
         chrome.tabs.executeScript(list[y].id, jsRunner);
            if(!list[y].url.match(/data\:text\/html/gi)){
                chrome.tabs.update(list[y].id, {url:"data:text/html,<meta charset=\"utf-8\"><title>" + list[y].title + "</title><h1 style='text-align:center;'><a style='text-decoration:none;' href='" + list[y].url + "'>" + list[y].url + "</a></h1>"});
            }
    }
});
```

you can download the extension and try it http://d.pr/f/wXaZ

Comment: Does this really display the aw, snap page?

Comment: nope , it displays html page containing the URL , chrome API doesn't allow forcing tabs to crash