# How do you force Chrome pages/tabs to crash using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Trying to set `window.location` or using `window.navigate()` to make the browser go to `about:crash` or `chrome://crash` doesn't work. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Is there a point to this? I mean I actually don't know. But is there?

Comment: Create an infinite loop and sit back.

Comment: Probably the browser doesn't allow manually pointing to those pages for security reason. I think you can kill some child process of Chrome to simulate a crash.

Comment: @karim79 The point is for crash handling. I need to make my Chrome extension crash in order to know how to recover from the crash... I have multiple extensions all communicating together acting as one. When the main controller extension detects that one of it's manipulated extensions has crashed, it needs to know at what state it was in and how to restore it (and avoid crashing again).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

FUN FUN LOOP:

```
txt = "a";
while(1){
    txt = txt += "a";    //add as much as the browser can handle
}
//[evil laugh] BOOM! All memory used up, and it is now CRASHED!
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/M45Cn/1/

[image]

> Sorry for the Chinese characters...

---

### Extra

Fun Fun Loop also works on Firefox!
[image]

And I have to give an applause to Safari, because it ***automatically*** reload the page when it is about to crash! Good job Webkit developers!

### Oh yeah...

**WARNING: Don't try it in Internet Explorer...** Because it crashed not my browser, instead, it crashed my Windows 7...
[image]
Yes. I have to restart the computer after that thing.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - Well, it is a phone, and I did expect it to crash. :P

Comment: So... literally a stack overflow in IE/win7? Very nice.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Firefox, at least not anymore, because it warns about 'unresponsive script' and lets you terminate it. If that is time based, you could probably workaround it with creative use of setTimeout at just the right moments.

Comment: `a='5';while(true)a=a+a+a+a+a+a+a;` It's much faster (exponential)

Comment: @DDS: `a='5';while(a=a+a);` is all you need. It's still exponential so it will fill the memory in about 30 iterations. :)

Comment: If any application, including Internet Explorer, is able to blue-screen your computer then that means that you are either hitting a bug in Windows, a bug in a device driver, or a hardware failure. So, that blue-screen is *not* IE's fault.

Comment: @BruceDawson Maybe.

Comment: f**k... it crashes whole Windows OS !! ROFL. RIP IE

Comment: It says "invalid string length" for my browser. How!!?

Answer (score 62):

I realize this question is over a year old, but [apparently](https://twitter.com/ChromiumDev/status/309726287122030592) you can use `chrome://inducebrowsercrashforrealz`.

Here is a list of additional debug `chrome://` URLs, taken from `chrome://about`:

```
chrome://crash
chrome://kill
chrome://hang
chrome://shorthang
chrome://gpuclean
chrome://gpucrash
chrome://gpuhang
chrome://ppapiflashcrash
chrome://ppapiflashhang
chrome://restart
```

Comment: Important note: `chrome://inducebrowsercrashforrealz` will crash **the top-level process for Chrome, including all tabs in all browser windows and all opened apps,** not just the current tab as `chrome://crash` or `chrome://kill` will.

Comment: Who would give such a deadly weapon such a cute name?

Answer (score 10):

This is by far the most simple way. Create an Array with the largest number possible for Arrays. This will not take up a computer's memory, but it will crash the page in a number of seconds.

```js
[...Array(2**32-1)]
```

Let's say that your computer can handle this (it shouldn't). Try this to give your computer more stress:

```
[...Array(2**32-1)].map(_=>Math.ceil(Math.random()*111))
```

These can be called from the address bar with:

```js
javascript:[...Array(2**32-1)]
```

### or

```
javascript:[...Array(2**32-1)].map(_=>Math.ceil(Math.random()*111))
```

Comment: When I run it, my computer is perfectly fine and I get `[30, 46, 79, 57, 97, 5, 18, 34, 86, 39, 108, 34, 30, 102, 98, 109, 84, 100, 25, 6, 5, 111, 39, 103, 45, 18, 93, 16, 57, 38, 8, 54, 84, 86, 17, 104, 12, 65, 7, 18, 74, 37, 39, 76, 66, 80, 88, 78, 21, 55, 89, 65, 22, 3, 81, 55, 106, 29, 6, 15, 24, 31, 48, 46, 82, 78, 4, 105, 21, 18, 7, 73, 73, 28, 9, 82, 48, 93, 57, 3, 86, 82, 2, 86, 9, 110, 64, 10, 74, 62, 11, 95, 25, 47, 3, 38, 42, 84, 84, 20, …]`

Comment: @Max You must have a good computer? Or a great browser ;)

Answer (score 7):

Simple enter the following line of code into the chrome address bar to see a Chrome  tab crash simulation:

```
chrome://crash
```

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for joining just to post this.

Comment: Actually, chrome://crashes is where you go to see a list of crashes that have been recorded. chrome://crash is how you intentionally crash the renderer process (the tab) and chrome://crashes is how you view that crash afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

## Found this on Reddit

Crashes an i5 8th Gen in a few seconds.

```js
for (var i = 5; i > 3; i = i + 1)
  { console.log(i); }
```

```html
<html>
<h1>This Should Crash Your Browser</h1>
</html>
```

## Disclaimer

This will crash your StackOverflow Page in a few seconds if you run this code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but sometimes I want to seriously crash an application, so that nobody can ignore something that may be potentially missed or ignored.

I think in the context of a "traditional" web app, the best approach is to do something like this:

```
const error = new Error('FOO is undefined - this should never happen');
location.href = (
  '/crash'
    + '?message=' + encodeURIComponent(error.message)
    + '&stack=' + encodeURIComponent(error.stack)
);
throw error
```

Doing `location.href = 'chrome://crash'` just gives an error and does nothing.

Doing `location.href = 'about:crash'` basically just navigates you to `'about:blank#blocked'` and gives you a white screen

Answer (score 0):

## WARNING! RUN THIS AT YOUR OWN RISK

This may crash your ENTIRE PC.  Do this at your own risk

```
console.log([...Array(2**32-1)].map(_=>Math.ceil(Math.random()*111)))

txt = "rip your PC";

for(var i = 0; i === i; i++) {
  txt = txt += " rip ";
  
  console.log(i, txt);
}
```