# Get CSS styles of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element that has the following styles:

```
<div id="myElement" style="opacity: 0.9; cursor: auto; visibility: visible;"></div>
```

I want to make sure it always (`setInterval`?) has these styles, no more no less, NO changes at all. I wonder if its possible to retrive all styles of an element (inline CSS or external) and compare compare them to make sure there were not changes?

Comment: Why not make a class, then use `.hasClass("className");`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: An element can't have *only* those styles. If nothing else, it will have lots received through the cascade from the browser's internal stylesheet.

Comment: CSS doesn't change itself.  Why not stop the changes at the source?

Comment: Yes, you can use SetInterval, which checks for that string in the style attribute, and reset it if something has changed

Comment: @harpo, the OP is trying to detect if the user manually changes things in the console. [know this from another post]

Comment: The objective here is to make sure the user doesn't override the CSS and hide the element somehow (display:none, position:absolute etc..)

Comment: @karthikr — From the question "all styles of an element (inline CSS or external)" so that wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: @Nimbuz — You can't. It's the user's browser. They can do whatever they like in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

Comment: @Nimbuz What benefit is this? What is your aim?

Comment: @curt Aim is to NOT allow the user to hide the element by overriding the CSS (display none etc..)

Comment: @Nimbuz I understand that, but why does it matter?

Comment: Also bear in mind that the user could simply disable javascript.  Relying on client side to be bullet proof to user tampering is asking a bit much.

Comment: @Maloric Oh I have a check for that too.

Comment: Not bullet proof, but something to make it difficult for cheaters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single element I would not imagine that the performance difference between setting it and checking it first is significant.  You might as well just do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var t = setInterval(function(){
        $('#myElement').attr('style', 'opacity: 0.9; cursor: auto; visibility: visible;');
    }, 1000);
}
```

I realise that you would normally set the styles using $('#myElement').css, but as you want to ensure no new styles were added, setting the style attribute should achieve what you want.  Unfortunately it doesn't account for changes to the stylesheet or style blocks elsewhere on the page.  To do this you would have to make your style attribute a bit more comprehensive and include "!important" after each value.

Out of interest, why do you need to do this?  It sounds like there might be a better solution to the problem.

**Edit:**
If you want to stop the user using clearInterval, instead of

```
var t = setInterval(...);
```

Just use

```
setInterval(...);
```

As clearInterval requires the reference to the interval in order to clear it (correct me if I'm wrong here).  By not creating that reference the interval is still executed but not clearable.

Ultimately though I don't think there will be a fool proof method to achieve this.  It should however, prevent all but the most determined users with from hiding whatever it is you want them to see.

**Edit 2:**
If you just want to check the CSS it is possible but a bit of a pain as you would have to check each property in turn.  Using jQuery's css function you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        var el = $('#myElement');
        var tampered = false;
        if (el.css('display') != 'block') tampered = true;
        if (el.css('visibility') != 'visible') tampered = true;
        if (el.css('position') != 'static') tampered = true;
        ....
        if (tampered){
            // Do your thing
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: The objective here is to make sure the user doesn't override the CSS and hide the element somehow (display:none, position:absolute etc..)

Comment: setInterval() will not work because user can use clearInterval()?

Comment: And setting `style` won't work because the user can inject a stylesheet that adjusts different styles or uses `!important`.

Comment: Even if the user uses !important in an injected stylesheet, adding !important to the inline styles will always give them precedent.

Comment: I'm not looking to play cat and mouse, if changes detected, I'll crash the browser :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965987/how-do-you-force-chrome-pages-tabs-to-crash-using-javascript

Comment: Instead of setting these CSS properties, can't I detect changes? Cause the CSS is already set, I just need to detect changes and do X

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to just read the css that has been applied.

Comment: @Maloric — Still not sufficient. There are many, many properties that could be added that would remove the element from sight.

Comment: @Quentin I'm open to better suggestions.  As I said, I don't believe there is a bullet proof method.  For each one of those properties, add another line.  I've listed three of the major ones.  You could also try width, height, opacity to name a few.

Comment: I'm using a different approach. I'm checking if the element is within the viewport, and is visible, if not .. do X