# Can we crash browser forcefully using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, crash

Is there any way to crash the browser(chrome, firefox, IE) forcefully running some javascript/jquery code?

Comment: Crash in the sense, do you want to close the browser automatically on some event occurrence ?

Comment: You have to describe what you mean by "crash".

Comment: This will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965987/how-do-you-force-chrome-pages-tabs-to-crash-using-javascript

Comment: @Vicky - "Aw snap,something went wrong" kind of crash if possible.

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik - I tried loop thing but its not happening.!

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can't crash the browser using script, you can only crash the script. Browsers nowadays have protection for scripts that hang or use too much resources, and will stop the script.

There are no severe bugs left in the browsers, like for example the IE `<input type crash>` bug. You might be able to find some bug that allows you to crash one browser, but that's not likely to work in any other browser, and it's likely to be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

The best one:

```
while(true) { window.location.reload() }
```